# Difference between cURL and SOAP in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, curl, web

I am curious to know about different ways of implementing web services in PHP? Is there other ways except cURL and SOAP? How SOAP is different than cURL? Is there any similarities also between them? 
Thanks,
ursitesion

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a web service in PHP with [SoapServer](http://php.net/soapserver) or with PHP - return JSON creating a REST interface. There are other ways, such as [XML-RPC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlrpc.php), but I usually end using either SOAP or REST, I prefer REST whenever possible.

[Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is a tool that you can use to consume a web service, it's not used to create a web service.

Answer (score 1):

[REST or SOAP](https://www.guru99.com/comparison-between-web-services.html) reading that might help.

Probably best to think of cURL as just a way to send a request (eg GET,POST) to another server.

There are alternatives to cURL, including just straight file_get_contents()

Edit : replaced a rotted link.  Also, having used SOAP quite a lot since this first reply, I'd add that another main reason you'd prefer SOAP to REST would be if you have to absolutely, positively double check that every transaction was received, else have the opportunity to resend it. No doubt you can do this with a suitably designed REST webservice, but that would need careful design and testing.

Comment: Can we send an AJAX to a cURL service?

Comment: Typically Ajax communicates from the client, say the browser, back to Server A (the mother ship) which can then cURL out to Server B and get data.

Comment: That means... AJAX can not make any request to the cURL right.?? cURL service is only open to servers.?

Comment: @Cups The above link is expired.

Comment: Cheers, updated it with another similar link, added more of my own thoughts too.